# Como eliminar u ocultar un campo al utilizar forms en un proyecto django

Tags: html, django, django-forms, template, django-urls

Buenas tardes estimada comunidad, necesito si alguien puede guiarme y darme una dirección, estoy creando un proyecto con django 2.2 y al momento de crear el template de login, ocupo la siguiente linea de codigo en mi bloque llamado login_form

```html
<form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table >
        {{ form.as_table }}
        </table>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Ingresar" />
    </form>
```

pero al momento de ver el template, aparece un "checkbox" llamado recordarme, que no se de donde aparece, por lo cual quiero eliminar dicha linea, pero no se como hacerlo, intente con un Script llamado ocultar, pero no funciono, e intentado con style.display = 'none' y tampoco funciono, estoy cargando los datos con 'Adminlte3', ademas revise la carpeta donde esta el templaye 'adminlte/login.html' pero no tiene ese 'checkbox en el codigo', toda ayuda y posible solución es bienvenido y muchas gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El form debe tener ese campo "recordarme", simplemente eliminalo, en cambio si heredas de un form, averigua como se llama dicho campo y excluyelo.

Answer (score 0):

Para la siguiente vez seria muy recomendable que compartieras tu modelo

Pero si en tu modelo tienes

```
usuario = models.Charfield()
contraseña=models.----
```

tienes un parametro mas ya que al utilizar

> form.as_table

llamas a todos los campos del modelo

te aconsejaria colocar

```
<form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table >
        {{ form.usuario }}
        {{ form.contraseña }}
        </table>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Ingresar" />
    </form>
```

De esta forma solo llamas a los campos que requieres

Comment: Hola y gracias por tu ayuda, se me olvido compartir el modelo, pero seguí tu consejo y esta es una manera de solucionarlo, pero también hay otra manera, ya que estoy trabajando con "adminlte", dentro del entorno virtual existe la carpeta "adminlte/allauth" te vas a  forms.py y alli esta el dichoso botón que se llama "remember", por lo cual solo lo borre y dejo de aparecer. Ojala todo estas respuestas sirvan para alguien en un futuro :)